# Wishing for money in Nethack

Tags: nethack

One may wish up to 5000 zorkmids in one wishing. How can I get more gold pieces through wishing?

I'm thinking of wishing for `two/three dilithium crystal`, which would give me at least one  dilithium crystal, whose base value is 4500 zorkmids. Is that OK?

Comment: Dilithium crystals can only be converted to zorkmids by shopkeepers, at a rate based on your charisma score, but limited by the shopkeeper's gold. What is it that you want gold for after acquiring a wish?

Comment: @Sconibulus Gold has many [uses](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Zorkmid#Use). I'm asking a general question about how to get as much gold as I can through wishing(which is usually a bad idea). Sometimes wishing is the only source of gold, say, when you accidentally break some unaffordable items in a shop, and you don't have escape items to leave the shop. I want to know how to minimize my lost in such a desperate situation where I must "waste" a wish.

Comment: How do you destroy *that* much value in a shop?  Gather the contents of a liquor emporium into a pile before snapping a wand of striking over them?

Comment: @tjd In fact you don't destroy goods worthing 5000 zorkmids. Say, you have 500 zorkmids in your inventory, and you read a scroll of fire by mistake when surrounded by scrolls of blessed charging/genocide/etc in a second-hand bookstore. If you are not carrying enough valuable scrolls/spellbooks, you are in trouble...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can wish for gems.  If you [wish for more than one](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Wish#Wishing_for_quantities), you'll only get one with probability *n* out of 6, where *n* is the number you wished for; otherwise you get the number you wanted.  Thus, wishing for 2–5 dilithium crystals gives you at least one (worth $4500), and possibly more:

```
# wished for | max value | success rate | avg. value
-------------+-----------+--------------+-----------
           1 |     $4500 |            1 |      $4500
           2 |     $9000 |          4/6 |      $7500
           3 |    $13500 |          3/6 |      $9000
           4 |    $18000 |          2/6 |      $9000
           5 |    $22500 |          1/6 |      $7500
          6+ |       n/a |          0/6 |      $4500
```

However, note that:

1. The gems obtained by wishing will be unidentified.  If you haven't identified dilithium crystals before, and cannot positively identify them (with a blessed [touchstone](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Touchstone), or with the spell or scroll of identify) before selling them, then [shopkeepers will cheat you](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Gem#Prices_when_unidentified) and only pay you a few zorkmids regardless of their true value.
2. Even if you can get the crystals identified, shopkeepers will only pay you at most 50% of their base value, and [may pay you less](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Price_identification#Shopkeepers_in_Nethack_3.4.3_and_earlier) depending on your class, level, worn equipment and just whether or not they feel like it (random 25% chance).
3. Each shopkeeper carries a limited amount of money, [initially between $1100 and $4000](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Shopkeeper).  Once they're out of cash, they will only give you store credit (for 90% of the usual sell price), which you can only use to buy items from that specific shop.  (Also, a bit annoyingly, if a shopkeeper can afford to pay only part of the sell price of an expensive item, they won't offer you credit for the remainder.)

Thus, even under ideal circumstances, the expect average profit from a wish for 3 or 4 dilithium crystals is only 50% × $9000 = $4500, which is less than the $5000 you could simply straight up wish for.  Of course, if you do get lucky and get the full amount of gems you wished for, then 3 or more dilithium crystals will typically sell for more than $5000, but getting that result is far from guaranteed.  And you'll never get all of that in cash, unless you've previously bought enough stuff from the shopkeeper with your own gold to make them extra wealthy.

Thus, if you're stuck in a shop with no money to pay your bill, but somehow happen to have a wish available, it's probably best to wish for:

- 5000 gold pieces, if that's enough to cover your debt,
- an [escape item](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Escape_item), such as a wand of teleportation, a wand of digging or a cursed potion of gain level,
- a [cockatrice](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Cockatrice) corpse  (remember to wear gloves!) or a [wand of death](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Wand_of_death) (make sure not to hit yourself on the rebound!) to kill the shopkeeper with, or
- a blessed [figurine](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Figurine) of an [Archon](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Archon).

Out of these options, the wand of digging and the cursed potion of gain level are probably the most reliable ones, being guaranteed to take you down or up a dungeon level respectively.  Their major down side, of course, is that you'll have to deal with an angry shopkeeper and a bunch of [Kops](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Keystone_Kop) the next time you return to that level.  Still, depending on where the shop is located and which direction you choose, you can at least spend a while in other parts of the dungeon to buff yourself up and/or to collect more gold to pay off the shopkeeper.

Stoning the shopkeeper with a cockatrice corpse, or zapping them with a wand of death, avoids this problem, but carries the risk that you'll miss and waste a turn (not to mention the intrinsic risks of both items, which can easily kill *you* if you're careless).  Shopkeepers have AC 0, so [the wand has a fixed 20% chance of missing.](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Wand#Hitting_and_missing)  (Bouncing the death ray off a wall can reduce this, but is very risky unless you have reflection.)  The hit chance for melee attacks depends on your [to-hit roll](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/To-hit), but is usually better than for wands; however, note that whacking things with a dead cockatrice doesn't benefit from any weapon skill bonuses.

The blessed figurine of an Archon, when applied, has an 80% chance of producing a tame Archon that should easily kill the shopkeeper; all you need to do is stay out of the way.  However, beware the 10% chance of the Archon being hostile instead.

You might also consider wishing for some generic combat item, such as [blessed greased fixed](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Wish#Other_options) +2 [SDSM](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Silver_dragon_scale_mail) (which will improve your AC and protect you from most of the wands carried by shopkeepers) or [GDSM](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Gray_dragon_scale_mail) (if you already have reflection from another source) or an [artifact](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Artifact) weapon such as [Grayswandir](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Grayswandir) or [Stormbringer](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Stormbringer), and hoping that it will be enough to let you fight the shopkeeper and win.  This has the advantage that the item you wish for can remain a useful part of your [ascension kit](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Ascension_kit) for the rest of the game, but carries the risk that, unless your other gear and stats are already fairly decent, a single powerful item may not be enough to let you survive the fight.

There are several other possible wishes that could be situationally useful.  For example, if you already have some means of polymorphing yourself, a ring of polymorph control might be useful.  Then again, you could just wish for S/GDSM and polymorph yourself while wearing it, which will turn you into a dragon that should be more than able to take on a shopkeeper.

Comment: Bear in mind, killing shopkeepers is MURDER, and entails penalties.  All players get an alignment penalty, and non-Chaotics lose 2 pts of Luck, as well as any intrinsic telepathy.  Wishing for a powerful pet (silver/gray dragons esp) to do the killing of shopkeeps is probably the best route, as they can quickly kill most (therefor no need to wish $), and should they die, you may get a set of scales.